# Nome collettivo degli animali dell'aia

Tags: vocabulary, nouns

Qual è l'insieme delle galline? E delle oche? Per le pecore è il gregge, per le vacche la mandria, ma per le galline mi viene solo covata che è solo per i pulcini.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Facendo alcune [ricerche](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormo) pare che *stormo* sia il corrispettivo di *branco* (*EDIT:* [Grazie a @PaoloFranchi] generalmente riferito ad un insieme di mammiferi, *ma si veda la citazione*) per designare una moltitudine di uccelli, specie se in volo:

> *([Il Corriere](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/stormo.shtml))* *Branco* di uccelli o di insetti in volo: ***s. di oche selvatiche***, di cavallette

e se ne trova qualche esempio in letteratura sia per le [oche](https://www.google.it/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=stormo+di+oche&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Y8uPVuusCsHD8geuo4qAAw#q=stormo+di+oche&channel=fs&tbm=bks) che per le [galline](https://www.google.it/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=stormo+di+oche&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Y8uPVuusCsHD8geuo4qAAw#channel=fs&tbm=bks&q=stormo+di+galline).

Altro termine utilizzato (col significato di "addensamento") è quello di [nugolo](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/nugolo/), anche qui sia per le [oche](https://www.google.it/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=nomi+collettivi&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=18OPVqyqDqyI8Qfr9J6wBQ#q=nugolo+di+oche&channel=fs&tbm=bks) che per le [galline](https://www.google.it/webhp?hl=it#q=nugolo+di+galline&hl=it&tbm=bks).

Come sinonimo di "branco" *[Il Corriere](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/F/frotta.shtml)* riporta anche "frotta":

> Gruppo numeroso di persone o di animali che procede senza alcun ordine SIN branco, moltitudine, stuolo: *una f. di ragazzi; una f. di cavalli*,

e anche in questo caso il termine viene adottato per l'[una](https://www.google.it/webhp?hl=it#hl=it&tbm=bks&q=frotta+di+galline) e per l'[altra](https://www.google.it/webhp?hl=it#hl=it&tbm=bks&q=frotta+di+oche) specie.

Infine, nonostante quanto riporta la [fonte](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stormo) precedentemente citata, si trovano esempi di uso di "branco" per gruppi di [oche](https://www.google.it/webhp?hl=it#hl=it&tbm=bks&q=branco+di+oche) e [galline](https://www.google.it/webhp?hl=it#hl=it&tbm=bks&q=branco+di+galline).

---

Per quanto concerne *[covata](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/covata/)*, il termine viene utilizzato nel significato di:

> Insieme delle uova che vengono deposte e covate nel nido dagli uccelli; nell’uso com., anche (seppure impropriam.) l’insieme dei pulcini dischiusi dopo ogni incubazione.

e infatti la ricerca secondo i metodi adottati precedentemente non dà risultati apprezzabili, né in un [caso](https://www.google.it/webhp?hl=it#hl=it&tbm=bks&q=covata+di+galline) né nell'[altro](https://www.google.it/webhp?hl=it#hl=it&tbm=bks&q=covata+di+galline).

Comment: Per le oche in volo è perfetto. Mi stavo fissando però su una situazione descritta da gaggle in inglese, ad esempio.

Comment: Scusami, avevo premuto il tasto "invio" per errore. Ho aggiornato la risposta.

Comment: Una piccola osservazione: in base a quanto riporta il Corriere alla voce "stormo", "branco" si può riferire anche ad animali diversi dai mammiferi (dato che viene espressamente scritto "branco di uccelli"), diventando quindi un termine generico, sinonimo di "gruppo"

Comment: @PaoloFranchi, grazie della segnalazione, mi era sfuggito.

Comment: @ErikvanDoren , perdonami ma non ho capito se ti stai rivolgendo a me e, in caso affermativo, a cosa ti riferisci.

Comment: @mrnld nono, scusa, in entrambi i miei interventi, mi riferivo al commento di 473183469, dove specifica esattamente il termine Inglese a cui si vuole riferire. Forse dovrei cancellare i due commenti ed unirli in uno correggendo la mancanza di @

Comment: @ErikvanDoren , nessun problema! ;) Credo che all'autore della domanda arrivino comunque le notifiche dei commenti lasciati qui sotto, ma per essere sicuri che li legga un edit con "@" per entrambi i tuoi commenti sarebbe l'ideale.

Comment: @473183469 credo che per correttezza dovresti usare la precisazione che hai fatto nel tuo commento, a proposito di gaggle, per correggere la tua domanda iniziale. Frotta sarebbe la traduzione più' giusta se intendi riportare l'idea di un gruppo disordinato come intendono per gaggle

Comment: Treccani: "Gruppo compatto di uccelli o di insetti in volo". Non ti do -1 ma le galline non c'entrano proprio niente con un gruppo compattodi uccelli in volo. 
Qualcuno fa notare che non esiste un termine specifico.

Comment: @maxadamo Infatti non ho affermato che *stormo* sia utilizzato propriamente per designare un *gruppo compatto di galline*, ma semplicemente che se ne trovano esempi in letteratura e che perciò il suo utilizzo in tale accezione è in qualche modo giustificato.

Answer (score 0):

Stormo indica un insieme di uccelli in volo. Anche se è spesso utilizzato per le galline, non credo sia esattamente corretto.

Le galline possono essere inserite nelle categorie "animali da reddito" o "animali da cortile", i nomi collettivi più adeguati credo siano **pollame** e per estensione **bestiame**:

[**Pollame**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pollame/): Denominazione collettiva e generica delle razze domestiche di gallinacei allevati per uso alimentare.

[**Bestiame**](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/bestiame/):In senso più ampio, vengono inclusi nel bestiame anche i cosiddetti animali da cortile (conigli, polli e altri volatili domestici).